# Синтаксический анализатор уравнений на чиcтом С

Tags: c, алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ, интерпретатор

Нужно реализовать программу решения уравнений на **чистом СИ**. Изначально для ввода самого уравнение реализовал следующее:

```
printf("Введите коэффициенты a, b и c");
scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);
```

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог вводить строку, например **4x^2-6x-2=0**, а программа распределила **4**, **-6** и **-2** по переменным **a**, **b** и **c** соответственно.

P.S. Возможна ли реализация следующей программы? Человек вводит уравнение разных типов (квадратное, кубическое, четвертой степени), а программа понимает, какой это тип и распределяет коэффициенты.

Comment: http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/revpn.php  Хотя конечно обратная польская запись далеко не единственный подход к синтаксическому разбору выражений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код на плюсах (и наверняка - некорректный), но идея от этого не меняется - определяем допустимые множества симводов и переходы между ними, от чего и пляшем дальше

```
enum TokenType {NONE, DOT, DIGIT, OPERATOR, VARIABLE};

struct Token {
  TokenType type;
  string    value;

  Token(type t, char v) {
    this.type = t;
    this.value = string(v);
  }
};

TokenType tokenType(char chr) {
  if (chr >= '0' && chr <= '9') return DIGIT;
  if (chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z') return VARIABLE;
  if (chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z') return VARIABLE;
  if (chr == '.') return DOT;
}

vector<Token> tokenize(string src) {
    vector<Token> tokens;
    TokenType old = NONE;
    char* c_src = src.c_str();
    while (*c_src) {
      TokenType type = tokenType(c_src);
      if ( (old == NONE) && (type == DIGIT || type == VARIABLE || type == OPERATOR)) {
        tokens.push(Token(type, *c_src));
      } else if (old == VARIABLE && (type == VARIABLE || type == DIGIT)) {
        tokens[tokens.size()-1].value += c_src;
      } else if (old == DIGIT && (type == DIGIT || type == DOT)) {
        tokens[tokens.size()-1].value += c_src;
      } else if (old == DIGIT && (type == VARIABLE || type == OPERATOR)) {
        tokens.push(Token(type, *c_src));
      } else if (old == VARIABLE && (type == OPERATOR)) {
        tokens.push(Token(type, *c_src));
      } else if (old == OPERATOR && (type == OPERATOR)) {
        tokens[tokens.size()-1].value += c_src;
      } else if (old == OPERATOR && (type == VARIABLE || type == DIGIT)) {
        tokens.push(Token(type, *c_src));
      }
      c_src++;
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что плюсы не знаю абсолютно. Да и алгоритм не очень понятен. Можете немного прожевать?

Comment: Я тут вижу только лексический разбор. А требуется еще синтаксический ...

Comment: По алгоритму - как верно заметили, это часть. Т.е. здесь происходит разбиение на отдельные токены : [4, x, ^, 2, -, 6, x, -2]. А вот дальше - в зависимости от задачи (и того, в какой форме даются уравнения). Можно разбить по разделителям +/- ([ [4,x,^,2], -, [6,x], -, [2] ]). Ну, думаю - дальнейшая работа вопросов не вызовет